# Android Studio Splash screen disappearing before activity start

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, splash-screen

I have problem with splash screen. It shows only for half a second and disappears a few seconds before activity HomeZastepowy appears. I made this splash screen based on this site https://android.jlelse.eu/right-way-to-create-splash-screen-on-android-e7f1709ba154. Where i made a mistake?

MainActivity code:

```
import android.content.Intent;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;

import java.util.Objects;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
     FirebaseAuth mAuth;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
            String uid = mAuth.getUid();
            final DocumentReference mDocRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("Data").document("userInfo").collection(Objects.requireNonNull(uid)).document(uid);
            mDocRef.get()
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                            if (documentSnapshot.exists()) {
                                String user = documentSnapshot.getString("user");
                                assert user != null;
                                if (user.equals("user")) {

                                    Log.d("tag", String.valueOf(mAuth.getUid()));

                                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                                            HomeUsrActivity.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                    finish();
                                } else {
                                    Log.d("tag", "Zastepowy");

                                    Log.d("tag", String.valueOf(mAuth.getUid()));

                                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, HomeZastepowy.class));

                                    finish();

                                }
                            }
                        }


                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            finish();


        }else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    HomeActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }


        }


    }
```

AndroidManifest code:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.zapp4">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_descriptor"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".HomeUsrActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".punktyog" />
        <activity android:name=".punktywz" />
        <activity android:name=".HomeZastepowy" />
        <activity android:name=".tradycje" />
        <activity android:name=".wiedza" />
        <activity android:name=".kontakt" />
        <activity android:name=".zastepy" />
        <activity android:name=".historia" />
        <activity android:name=".onas" />
        <activity android:name=".HomeActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:theme="@style/SplashScreenTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: I suggest your application takes too long to load.

Comment: What exactly do you want this code to do other than what you're observing?

Comment: @DougStevenson Splash screen should smoothly turn into HomeZastepowy. Now splash screen disappears too fast and app disappears for about 2 seconds. After this time, HomeZastepowy layout appears. Sorry for my english, I'm using google translator.

Comment: Are you sure that the other activity isn't just taking a long time to render?  have you tried adding log statements to show exactly when everything happens, so that you can debug where the delay is?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you forgot to remove this line from your code:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
```

Because you setContentView, it overrides your theme background. So try to comment this line and give it a try.